# Is There A Way To Know Function's Type Of Return Value Without Executing It?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of functions inside an object. One returns an object and the other one returns string:

```
{
  id: 'test-1',
  children: [
    function childOne() {
      return {
        id: 'child-1'
      }
    },
    function childTwo() {
      return 'text.'
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to detect type of a return value without executing functions?

Comment: Do you know the return type of each function, while pushing it into the array?

Comment: no, not least because depending on the code of the application, it might be possible for the function to return different data types in different circumstances.

Comment: Use : typeof https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @JagjeetSingh using typeof() would require the function to be executed (because it relies on reading the variable which the function returned), but OP mentioned they wanted to detect it without executing the function

Comment: @JagjeetSingh `typeof()` does not work until `()` initiate the function, which means you actually executed the function when you insert input

Comment: You could parse the text of the function and check everything that comes after a `return`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance what if that's just a variable name, how would you know its type?

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, it's not a general solution. I guess you would have to go through the code and look for where said variable is assigned, and so on. Better to use something built for this sort of thing already

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in JavaScript, no, because:

- Declaring a return type isn't a JavaScript concept.
- Even if you used a parser to parse the function's source, functions can return different types depending on their inputs, the state they close over, the time you happen to look, or even at random.

[TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org) adds a layer of static type checking to JavaScript, if this is something that you regularly find you need. But even then, that information is erased at runtime, so if you need this information at runtime, TypeScript won't help.

Instead, you'll need to include that as information in the array, for instance:

```
{
  id: 'test-1',
  children: [
    {
      returns: "object",
      fn: function childOne() {
        return {
          id: 'child-1'
        };
      }
    },
    {
      returns: "string",
      fn: function childTwo() {
        return 'text.';
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, since functions are objects:

```
{
  id: 'test-1',
  children: [
    addReturns("object", function childOne() {
      return {
        id: 'child-1'
      }
    }),
    addReturns("string", function childTwo() {
      return 'text.'
    })
  ]
}
```

...where `addReturns` is:

```
function addReturns(type, fn) {
  fn.returns = type;
  return fn;
}
```

Comment: I can't use or i don't want to use a parser because this is a runtime code. Including the information as a property or parameter is the best option i saw so far.

Comment: @muratgozel - Yeah, and again, a parser only gets you so far. For instance: `function foo() { return someVariableFooClosesOver; }` -- what type does it return? You'd have to know what `someVariableFooClosesOver` is in whatever context it is that `foo` closes over. In fact, it could even vary depending on when you looked (if `someVariableFooClosesOver` is 1 at one time but `"blah"` at another time). (And `foo` could do different things on different paths.)